# Plus + Character disappears

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

For some reason when I render a template that contains the + sign it disappears, no errors or anything just gone.

I am rendering it like this

```
rc = RequestContext(request, template_context_dict)

html_content = smart_str(Template(updated_template_source).render(rc))
```

it is still there when I check the request and rc, but after it is being rendered it is gone.

Thanks

Comment: What does the portion of the template containing the + look like?

Comment: Can you post some code we can run in order to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's something to do with [autoescape](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs). 
Maybe try

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

and see if it still doesn't render.